# Better Gmail 2 Firefox Addon for Fluid (Site Specific Browser for OS X)

Tags: macos, firefox, gmail, browser-addons, fluid

Is there a simple way to get the [Better Gmail 2](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6076) addon to work in [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got around to this.Thought it would be easier, but in the end it was VERY easy.

Instructions for Fluid (once you have your Fluid set up, of course):

1. Go [here](http://arendvr.com/folders4gmail/) and click on the link for `InstallFolders4GmailUserscript`.
2. This will take you to the Javascipt source. Select all and copy to your clipboard.
3. In Fluid, under the scripts menu, select `New Userscript` and call it Folders4Gmail (or "Joe").
4. Ignoring the contents of the script skeleton it provides, just paste in the stuff you copied in #2
5. Reload your Gmail and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to install all of the greasemonkey scripts that are listed on this page:
http://groups.google.com/group/better-gmail-2-firefox-extension/web/better-gmail-2-complete-user-script-listing

The way you would go about doing is to go in the Fluid preferences for your gmail ssb and choose userscripts. Add "mail.google.com" to the list of servers up top and paste the greasemonkey script underneath.

I'm not sure if all of those scripts will actually work with fluid though. A lot of them will, but probably some won't because fluid is based on webkit and they were made for firefox, which is gecko.

Comment: Is that possible? Fluid is based on webkit, like Safari, I seriously doubt if a Firefox addon would "just work" on that..

Comment: Niels Bom: yes, I did a piece of this for the Folders4Gmail. Ninique: thanks! That helped me realize that there was no easy way out.